# Installation request for zofe/rapyd dev-master

Tags: content-management-system, laravel-5.5

After cloning & while doing composer update I am getting the error :

- Installation request for zofe/rapyd dev-master
- Conclusion: don't install intervention/image 2.4.2
- .......
- ......
- ......

I am using xampp 7.2.8 , composer 1.7.1, Windows 10 in Virtualbox.

I have cloned the created database, but unable to run the composer update or php artisan migrate as mentioned in https://github.com/raylight75/cms#official-documentation .

Could someone help me ?

I have posted the same issue in https://github.com/raylight75/cms/issues/8

Comment: Can you post the full log from composer? Are you getting any actual errors?

Comment: https://justpaste.it/450lv

Answer (score 0):

From the `composer` log you've posted, it looks like the package you are trying to install `zofe/rapyd@dev-master` is not compatible with the version of Laravel you're using.

The log you've posted also differs to the error you've posted in your question. There is no mention of `intervention/image` in the logs. Instead, the log is showing an issue with `laravelcollective/html` and `nesbot/carbon`.

Try installing the latest stable version by updating the `composer.json` file and changing the version from `dev-master` to `~2.2`. The latest stable version is v2.2.7, while version 2.6.3 is pre-release, but supports Laravel 5.6.

The issue may also be fixed by updating your version of Laravel to v5.6. However, this is likely to be more work than just using a lower version of `zofe/rapyd`.